# What is the difference between "app" and "app$" in Intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using `Intellij` to develop `Scala` program. When click `run`, it displays two applications:`HelloWorld` and `HelloWorld$`:
[image]

What is the difference between the 2 applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `jvm` `HelloWorld$` is the class of singleton `HelloWorld`.

Scala generates `ObjectName$` class for every object `ObjectName`.

It also creates static methods in this class that looks like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MODULE$.main(args);
}
```

From `java`you could either get an instance of object `ObjectName` using `ObjectName$.MODULE$` static field, or call static proxy methods on `ObjectName$`.